# How to get a website's position setup in a way that an image is centred?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, positioning

That title may not be the best, here's an example of what I'm looking for: http://www.teslamotors.com/en_CA/models

Notice how the image stays in the middle, and gets "shrunk" or reduced from both sides evenly, up to a certain width, and then the website stops shrinking.

I've tried my best, but can only achieve this in javascript using the window.onresize event call, and was wondering if there was a CSS way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to apply a percentage `width`, along with a fixed `min-width`, and `margin: 0 auto` to keep it centered

```
.content {
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/isohAQe/1